# Append a PHP code with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to insert a new field in a div when the user clicks on the button (+).

The code of textfield is that:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT nome, codigo FROM ref_bibliograficas";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
echo ("<select class='autocomplete big' name='ref_bib_0' style='width:690px;' required>");
echo ("<option select='selected' value=''/>");  
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo ("<option value=" . $row["codigo"] . ">" . $row["nome"] . "</option>");
echo ("</select>");
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

So, i don't know how I insert the field with AJAX.

I maked the function onclick with jQuery! Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the jQuery `.load()` function. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Have your php page output the desired HTML that you want to add to your div, then your JavaScript code should look something like this:

```
$('#addButton').click(function(){          // Click event handler for the + button. Replace #addButton wit the actual id of your + button
    $('#myDiv').load('yourphppage.php');   // This loads the output of your php page into your div. Replace #myDiv with the actual id of your div
});
```

If you want to *append* a new field to your div, then you should do the following:

```
$('#addButton').click(function(){  
    $.post('yourphppage.php', function(data) {
        $('#myDiv').append(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax Approach**

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
  $('#plus-button').click(function(e)
  {
    $.ajax(
    {
    url: "PHP-PAGE-PATH.php", // path to your PHP file
    dataType:"html",
    success: function(data)
    {
       // If you want to add the data at the bottom of the <div> use .append()

       $('#load-into-div').append(data); // load-into-div is the ID of the DIV where you load the <select>

       // Or if you want to add the data at the top of the div

       $('#load-into-div').prepend(data); // Prepend will add the new data at the top of the selector
    } // success
    }); // ajax
   }

});
```